# How to place a wrapfigure on top of the page?

Tags: vertical-alignment, positioning, subfloats, wrapfigure

Consider the following code

```
  \subsection{Seleção da Dosagem Ótima}
%
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \captionsetup{width=0.45\textwidth}
    \subfloat[Parte inicial: adição de acidificante $HCl\ 0,5\%$]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{IMG-20160608-WA0013}}\\
    \subfloat[Iniciazão da flotação]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{IMG-20160608-WA0010}}\\
    \subfloat[Parte final da flotação e lodo flotado]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{IMG-20160608-WA0014}}
    \caption{Fases do ensaio de flotação para a seleção da dosagem ótima}
    \label{fig:fotosflotacao}
\end{wrapfigure}
%
O objetivo desta etapa foi selecionar a dose ótima de quitosana, usando como base o potencial zeta após coagulação e a remoção de cor e turbidez do processo de flotação sem a adição de carvão ativado. No começo do ensaio, foi adicionado $HCl\ 0.5\%$ como acidificante, seguidamente se deu inicio à mistura rápida, com um gradiente de velocidade de $700\ s^{-1}$ durante 30 segundos, e imediatamente foi adicionada quitosana nas diferentes dosagens. O pH de coagulação foi de $6,57\pm0,029$. A floculação teve um gradiente de velocidade de $50\ s^{-1}$ durante 15 minutos a parte inicial e final da flotação podem ser observados na figura \ref{fig:fotosflotacao}. Os resultados obtidos podem ser observados na figura \ref{fig:Remocao_Inicial}.\par
%
Na figura \ref{fig:remoc_Inicial} pode se observar que as dosagens de $0,5$ e $0,75\ mg/L$ apresentaram melhore remoção que a dosagem de $0,25\ mg/L$; alcançando remoções de turbidez de 93,15\% e 89,36\% e de cor de 99,09\% e 88,49\% respectivamente. Na figura \ref{fig:PotenZ_Inicial} observa-se que apesar de que a dosagem de $0,5\ mg/L$ mostrou remoções levemente superiores, a carga superficial das partículas esteve um pouco mais distante da neutralidade que na dosagem de $0,75\ mg/L$. Na dosagem de $0,5\ mg/L$ a carga superficial das partículas permanece negativa, já na dosagem de $0,75\ mg/L$ se observa uma carga superficial mais próxima da neutralidade, porém se evidencia uma reestabilização de cargas devido ao seu valor positivo, o que indica que a quitosana age pelo mecanismo de coagulação de adsorção e neutralização de cargas.Com base nessas informações, a dosagem de $0,75 mg/L$ foi selecionada como a dosagem ótima do dia, e esta foi utilizada no desenvolvimento das etapas 2 e 3.\par
%
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \captionsetup{width=0.35\textwidth}
        \subfloat[Remoção de cor e turbidez obtida pelas diferentes dosagens de quitosana]{\label{fig:remoc_Inicial}
        \begin{minipage}[c][0.25\textwidth]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Remocao_Inicial}
        \end{minipage}}
    \subfloat[Potencial Zeta após coagulação de cada dosagem de quitosana]{\label{fig:PotenZ_Inicial}
        \begin{minipage}[c][0.25\textwidth]{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PotencialZ_Inicial}
        \end{minipage}}
        \captionsetup{width=\textwidth}
    \caption{Parâmetros para a seleção da dosagem ótima do dia}
    \label{fig:Remocao_Inicial}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

How can I put the wraped figure on the top of te page and avoid the slope between the figures?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think this is feasible (at least automatically) with `wrapfigure`.

Comment: Please post complete code, though, in case you do ask a feasible question ;).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you let tex page break normally and note where it breaks the page you can force a "hidden" paragraph break at exactly that spot and insert th ewrapfig:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\section{aaa}

aaaa
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten

\rule{1cm}{15cm}

\section{bbbb}

one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four{% tex broke the page here!!!!
\parfillskip=0pt
\parskip=0pt
\par}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{zzz}
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten

one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten

one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you still have to count lines this way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\section{aaa}

aaaa
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten

\rule{1cm}{15cm}

\afterpage{\hfill\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]%
  {\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{zzz}
  \end{minipage}}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}

\section{bbbb}
\hangindent=\dimexpr -0.5\textwidth-\columnsep\relax
\hangafter=2
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten

\rightskip=\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth+\columnsep\relax
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten

\rightskip=0pt
\hangindent=\dimexpr -0.5\textwidth-\columnsep\relax
\hangafter=-1
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten

\end{document}
```